# Hibernate Criteria Inner Join Query

Tags: java, hibernate

Is anyone know how to write following sql query using Hibernate Criteria :

```
select log1.Status, nm.TransactionId,* from NonMemberTransaction nm
inner join
(
    SELECT status,NonMemberTransactionId
    FROM MessagingLog m1
    WHERE CreatedDate = (select max(CreatedDate) from MessagingLog m2 where m1.NonMemberTransactionId=m2.NonMemberTransactionId)
) log1
on nm.TransactionId=log1.NonMemberTransactionId
```

Thanks

Comment: First show us what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but i advise not to do it like this. Hibernate is a persistence framework, but your sql is language-specific and readonly.

I suggest to use a database [view](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL)) because of

- performance
- agility
- not language-specific anymore,
- easy to understand for programmers

Optional you can write a hibernate-entity for the view.

The query you have models informations about the database, so its the pronounced task of the [database itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database)!